# (Seeking Original Source in  Yechave Daas ) Limiting instances of doing something 3 times becoming a neder

Tags: sources-mekorot, nedarim-shevuot, hacham-ovadia-yosef

According to Harav Musafi Shelit"a (Q&A 74259) (and I'm sure earlier sources), if you do a "Hanhaga Tova - good deed" three times you need Hatarat Nedarim. I believe Harav Ovadia Shelit"a in his book Yechave Daas holds that this only applies for Hanhagot mentioned in the Shulhan Aruch. Can anyone provide the source in Yechave Daat where he says this?

Comment: Question Verification:  3x a good deed is a neder.  You want to know where in black and white Rav Ovadia limits this to certain things?

Comment: @R'YDK precisely.

Comment: I hope I edited your question correctly.

Comment: @YDK Thank you. I pretty sure he writes this just I'm not exactly sure where.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I have edited the question title to (in my mind) better reflect the question asked. If you disagree, please change it back.

Comment: @R'DoubleAA Ashrecha for the final touches.

Comment: HachamGabriel You should know that when the computer decides who to ping in a comment, it looks at the first few characters after the @ sign. So it might be more effective to write R' @DoubleAA (although I don't see why I deserve that title).

Comment: @DoubleAA [related](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/593/revisions)

Comment: HachamGabriel I thought from your title that you were looking for a source for the main idea that doing something 3 times creates a Neder. I also see there's a deleted answer from someone who thought so, too. Please forgive me if I got it wrong, but I thought the title could use further clarification (beyond the change that @DoubleAA already made).

Comment: I'm curious why someone would think that all things if done 3 times become a neder. IF I serve pizza 3 times does that mean that I now always have to serve pizza?

Comment: @Vram good point...

Comment: A Bar-Ilan search of Yechave Da'at of the words `התרת נדרים שלשה` throughout turned up with nothing of the sort. Check 2:70 for a *similar* idea though (nothing about the number 3).

Comment: related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16967/upper-limits-of-kovea-itim/16969#16969

Answer (score 2):

In Yechave Da'at 2,70 R' Ovadia discusses women's obligation to keep their minhag of keeping Mitzvot Asseh Shehazman Graman. He generally holds that since they are not obligated - the fact that they kept something 3 times does not make it a neder.   The is also a similar and longer response on Yabia Omer 2 Orach Chayim 30.