# Is there a source that obliges attendance at a shiur after say several years of attendance?

Tags: halacha, adult-learning

Is there a halakhic or hashkafic source for the idea that if I attended a shiur over a period of time, this creates an obligation on me to continue to attend?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13999

Comment: see this answer, which talks about commitment to learn becomes like a neder, perhaps the same thing applies here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16969/603