# Does determining the proper action in scenario X count towards Talmud Torah?

Tags: torah-study, speech-talking

Say you are about to perform some action. You then realize that there might be some halachic issues involved. You begin to enter a thought process about what is the halachically right thing to do.

Does entering this thought process count towards Talmud Torah, even if there is no speech involved?

Comment: Sounds like the ultimate Talmud Torah; where practice meets implementation. Now to find a good source...

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: What are you asking? Whether or not you get reward for doing the mitzvah of talmud Torah? Whether you can do this before making birkas hatorah? If you can do this in the bathroom? Are you specifically asking about a *thought process* as opposed to speaking it out?

Comment: Matt, the last sentence doesn't make that clear? We have an obligation to study Torah; does this thought process exempt you from that obligation?

Comment: @AniYodea I edited your question (and posted an answer) based on your above comment.  If it is not correct, please edit and notify me with a ping.

Comment: @AniYodea no, I wasn't sure if you're question was based on the fact that it was merely a *thought process*, or because it was related to a *specific action*.

Comment: your recent comment your recent comment still has me confused. What do you mean *exempt you from that obligation*? That isn't really how this mitzvah works, though it's a bit complicated, and [a totally separate question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/kevias-ittim-vs-the-general-mitzva-of-talmud-torah) (and [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30840/are-there-sources-that-any-minute-not-learned-torah-is-a-sin/35740#35740))

Comment: @Matt, Jews are obligated to learn during the day and during the night. Say you didn't pray/learn any torah whatsoever during the day, does entering into such a thought process fulfill that day's obligation of Talmut Torah (assuming you do some learning at night)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does listening to Torah content count as the mitzvah of Talmud Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/does-listening-to-torah-content-count-as-the-mitzvah-of-talmud-torah)

Answer (score 3):

The Maharal in [Nesiv HaTorah towards the end of chapter 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14202&st=&pgnum=26) writes that one does not need to make a Birkas haTorah on thoughts of Torah.  The Maharal explains that this is because a person is defined by speech, as Onkelos translates ויהי האדם לנפש חיה, Man became a living being, as רוח ממללא, a speaking being.  Man is defined by the intersect between the intellect and the body, which is exemplified in the bringing out of the thought into speech, which requires the combination of intellect and action (this is expanded in Gevuros Hashem ch. 28). The intellect, and therefore thought, is not *really* part of the person (this is expanded on in ch. 9), and therefore involvement in Torah in thought is not *really* the person himself being involved.  It is only through speech that the person is considered to himself be involved in Torah.

The Maharal does not explicitly say that this is not considered Talmud Torah, but the implication of not requiring the Birkas haTorah implies that this is not a fulfillment of the mitzvah of Talmud Torah.

Comment: Do we paskin this way? If we did then anyone reading a torah book without verbalizing the words would not be fulfilling Talmud Torah.

Comment: @AniYodea I don't know how "we" pasken, but this site isn't for paskening.  In any event, the Maharal there brings several reasons why you should be learning out loud anyways.

Comment: By we I mean the modern day poskim - not the users of this site.

Comment: @AniYodea fulfilling the mitzvah of talmud Torah and the requirement to make birkas hatorah are not necessarily the same. It's a complicated issue