# How exactly does one fulfill Kove'a Itim La'Torah?

Tags: torah-study, time

There is an obligation to set "times for learning torah." How exactly does one fulfill this obligation? Do you have to designate specific times in the day e.g. 9-9:30 am, or can it be a specific amount of time of learning each day at any time? And does it have to be time specifically? (As opposed to pages, etc.) sources, please.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16971/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16968/759

Comment: The ש״ע you led me to doesn't fully address my problem, what I meant is does somebody have to set 9-9:30 everyday or can he set (for example) 1 hour after shacharit each morning (which could change depending on when he prays

Answer (score 2):

The obligation to set aside time daily to learn Torah is discussed in Shulchan Aruch OC [Siman 155](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94) and [Siman 238](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%97). The wording of Shulchan Aruch ("He should establish a time to learn. This time should be set, and he should not skip it, even if he things he will make allot of profit") seems to imply it should be a specific time in the day. The [Seder Hayom](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41230&st=&pgnum=27) (a contemporary of the Beis Yosef) and Kaf HaChaim ([Ois 13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=357&hilite=)) both emphasize it should be a set time in the day.

The question whether it should be a set amount of time or a set amount of material is discussed in the Sefer "Betoraso Yehege" (pg. 339 footnote 11). From the above sources it would seem it should be a an amount of time, however the Mishna Berura in OC 238:2 seems to imply it could be an amount of pages. He writes that R' Chaim Kanievesky wrote to him that either is acceptable.